# Find normal distribution parameters from cdf

Tags: normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Given a random variable $X \sim Norm(\mu, \sigma)$, which we know that 20% of observation are less than 1.2 while 90% of observations are less than 1.4, how can we estimate the parameters $\mu, \sigma$? Hence, given $\Phi_{X}(1.2)=0.2$ and $\Phi_{X}(1.4)=0.9$, find $\mu, \sigma$. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I am currently looking to find methods to solve the given problem, not necessarily a solution. If I'll find more context I'll surely provide it for further viewers.

Comment: Hint: if the CDF $\Phi$ of an $N(0,\,1)$ distribution has inverse $\Phi^{-1}$ then$$\frac{1.2-\mu}{\sigma}=\Phi^{-1}(0.2),\,\frac{1.4-\mu}{\sigma}=\Phi^{-1}(0.9).$$

Answer (score 0):

Given that,  $\Phi^{-1}(0.2)=-0.842=P(z<-0.842)=0.2$, and $\Phi^{-1}(0.9)=1.282=P(z<1.282)=0.9$:

Solving the following system for $\mu, \sigma$, $(\mu+1.282\sigma=1.4,  
\mu-0.842\sigma=1.2)$ will return the parameters which are $\mu=1.2792$ and $\sigma=0.09416$.